# I am doing a pivoting and I want to do two aggregates for 2 different fields, but pivoting for the same field

Tags: sql, pivot, aggregate

I am doing a Pivot and I want to do two aggregates for 2 different fields, but pivoting for the same field. What are my options?

For example:

```
Select feild1, field2, field3, field4
From (select fld1, fld2, fld3, Field3, Field4 from tbl1) as ABC_Tbl
Pivot
(max(fld1) for Field3) as pvt1
(max(fld2) for Field3) as pvt2
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend conditional aggregation:

```
select fld1,
       max(case when fld2 = 'a' then fld4 end) as fld2_a,
       . . . ,
       max(case when fld3 = 'a' then fld4 end) as fld3_a,
       . . . 
from tbl1
group by fld1
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, That might work but I also need to do a pivot in this table and I am trying to Pivot this with the 2 aggregates. Do you have any other recommendations for that?

Comment: @Mahee . . . This DOES pivot the table.  Probably more efficiently too.

Comment: This really did it. Thanks a million !